# Incorrect pid of calling process when handling signal in C

Tags: c, linux, signals, pid

I really do not know what exactly I am doing wrong here. I want to extract a caller's pid from incoming signal, but the value I get is totally incorrect.

Here's my code for "catcher":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int SIGNALS_RECEIVED = 0;
pid_t CALLING_PID;

void signal_received(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
    SIGNALS_RECEIVED++;

    if(SIGNALS_RECEIVED == 1) {
        CALLING_PID = info->si_pid;
        printf("%ld\n", (long) CALLING_PID);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_sigaction = &signal_received;

    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL);

    while(1) {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And "sender":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[10];
    FILE *cmd = popen("pidof -s catcher", "r");

    fgets(line, 10, cmd);
    pid_t pid = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);

    pclose(cmd);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    }

    kill(pid, SIGUSR2);

    return 0;
}
```

As a result, when running at first catcher, and then sender, I get:

```
./catcher 
398533948
SIGNALS_RECEIVED: 24
```

While sender's pid is:

```
ps aux | grep *sender
maciej    4704  100  0.0   4328  1268 pts/13   R+   22:46   0:15 ./sender
```

My Linux version:

```
Linux version 4.2.0-34-generic (buildd@lgw01-55) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #39~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:38:02 UTC 2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the man page for `sigaction()`:

> `sa_handler` specifies the action to be associated with `signum` ... This function receives the signal number as its only argument.

That is not what you want. You want this instead:

> If `SA_SIGINFO` is specified in `sa_flags`, then `sa_sigaction` (instead of `sa_handler`) specifies the signal-handling function for `signum`.  This function receives the signal number as its first argument, a pointer to a `siginfo_t` as its second argument ...

You didn't set the `SA_SIGINFO`flag when you installed the handler.

Add the following line to your code before calling `sigaction`:

```
act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
```